# PL/R function accepting two tables as arguments

Tags: r, postgresql, plpgsql, plr

I'm struggling to find an examples of a PL/R function that could accepts two postgres tables. [PL/R docs](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/doc/index.html) does not provide any such example.
To have a working examples lets considering using merge of two postgres tables on R side.

Having two tables in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE x (a numeric, b text);
CREATE TABLE y (a numeric, d text);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, 'a'),(2, 'b');
INSERT INTO y VALUES (2, 'b'),(3, 'c');
```

I'm looking to replace following query

```
SELECT * FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.a=y.a;
```

With the PL/R function defined in R as:

```
my_function = function(x, y){
    merge(x, y, by = "a")
}
```

I was able to call PL/R function which accepts single table, but not two.

Comment: This is not impossible in (postgres) SQL, you just need dynamic SQL: generate an SQL query which uses the table- and column-names, and execute this query, returning the resulting rows. ( the `by= "a"` form of parameter passing probably needs to be changed a bit)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that postgeql can accept real table as parameters.

But there is another way to do it. You can pass the table names as parameters.
Here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge(t1 text, t2 text)
returns setof x as 
   BEGIN
     execute 'select * from ' || t1 ||' join ' || t2 || ' on t1.a=t2.a';
   END
```

The above is the function for postgresql, it can also written in the R function.
Here is the code for R

1. We have to store all the values of table x into a variable x. See the codes below

   `x <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from sandbox.x")` --con is the connection which connect to your db, sandbox is the schema name, x is the table name
2. Store values of table y into a variable y

   `y<-dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from sandbox.y")`
3. merge the 2 tables

   `total <- merge(x,y,by="a")`
4. You can also write another function to wrapper the merge function, see the codes below

   `myTotal <- function(x,y) {`
        `result <- merge(x,y,by="a")`
         `return(result)`
       `}`

I attached a screenshot of the steps for your reference

[image]

Comment: There do have function which you merge two table in R codes. First, you have to create 2 data frames (datasets), the data frames should match the definition of your tables. Then you can use the build-in function merge, see the codes below                                             total <- merge(data frameA,data frameB,by="a"). Is this what you want?

Comment: I have update my answer, you can take a look at. let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @Robinson I came up with the same answer. You beat me to it. There are packages for connecting to postgres such as RPostgreSQL.  PL/R seem a little light on support for other OS's. i can't for the life of me see why the name of a table is not enough, since the Sql is executed as text. As a side note  "MERGE is not in 9.4.5 (the latest PostgreSQL release as of 2015-10-08) UPSERT functionality will be in the PostgreSQL 9.5 release -- see What's new in PostgreSQL 9.5 " Ref https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

Comment: @pnorton when I refer table in my posts, I am referring the table object(which contains table definition, including primary key, constrains and data) not the table name. To be more clear, jangorecki want to do the join in the R side not postgresql. It is possible. I have updated the codes in the R side.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm RPostgreSQL power-user already. I've asked question expecting to get precise answer. @pnorton I've already incorporated UPSERT using RPostgreSQL in R package [pg](https://github.com/jangorecki/pg) using staging table behind the scene.

Comment: @Robinson it doesn't really answer the question